# How to write a int* to char[]?

Tags: c++

I have

```
int some_var = 5;
int* ref_on_var = &a;
char arr[8];
char* to_write = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ref_on_var);
```

I want to write ref_*on_var* to arr so i write this

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int*); ++i)
{
     arr[i] = to_write[i];
}
```

This writes some bytes to array but when I try to get pointer back by

```
int* get = reinterpret_cast<int*>(arr);
```

I get incorrect address.
So what do I do wrong?

Comment: Well, `sizeof(int *)` may or may not be the same as `sizeof(int)`, think hard about which one is the right one. Additionally, what does "incorrect address" mean? How did you determine it was "incorrect"? What would be the correct one?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik When ref_on_var and get point at the same value(some_var). I want to write address of some_var to array.

Comment: An `int *` is a pointer, so I'm assuming you want to write a pointer to C-style string (`char []`).  Try this:  `char s[2048]; int * a = new a; sprintf(s, "%p", a);`

Comment: It's still difficult to understand what the intent is here, but I think you want `int* get = *reinterpret_cast<int**>(arr);`.

Comment: If you want to print the target of a pointer, to a string, try this:  `int a = 5; int * p_a = &a; char s[128]; sprintf(s, "%d", (*p_a));`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is correct. Thanks! Can you write the answer to mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr`

This evaluates to a pointer to `arr`, that's the result of using the name of an array in a C++ expression.

This `char` buffer contains an `int *`, therefore this must be an `int **`. So:

```
int* get = *reinterpret_cast<int**>(arr);
```